# Powershell: Sync Delay in onboarding a user

Tags: powershell

We have a script that runs to onboard a user once someone raises a request for him/her, but the request is made way before the joining date.

A user might be joining 2 months from now, but the client has confirmed their joining, so raises an onboarding request.

Once in place it gets completed and all necessary changes happen in AD, Sharepoint profile is created etc. This profile is then visible way before the user has even joined.

So, to overcome this issue we have come up with a sync delay to make the user active in Sharepoint and in AD a few days before the joining date like 1 week before.

I'm looking for input on how this could be achieved in powershell script?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [ask] as your questions is lacking alot of the basics. At the moment it's hard to advise when we don't know about your existing processes or script. Is it manually run or automated? How does it take input? What inputs does it take etc... The obvious answer is to update your script so it only creates the accounts when the users start date is with X days of todays date?

Answer (score 0):

Create the user account with `Enabled` set to `false`.
Set a scheduled task to enable the account on the date of you choice.